# XDS100v2 OpenOCD Support

Tags: jtag, texas-instruments, openocd

I've read a lot of post saying that TIs XDS100v2 JTAG emulator is not supported by OpenOCD. However, looking at this [link](http://openocd.net/), I see that the XDS100v2 is a supported FTDI chip. So I'm kind of confused on if it is or not. I do have a license for Code Composer Studio but It may not always be available so I would like to have a backup plan.

Comment: I dont have any problems using openocd with an XDS100V2 board

Comment: CCS not required.   what have you tried so far and what did it do or not do?

Comment: I don't have an XDS100v2 board currently. I wanted to make sure it's what I want. But I think it's a pretty good option.

Answer (score 1):

OpenOCD ships config files for XDS100v2, so it is supported.

But you may need a different driver for OpenOCD that would prevent you from using CCS.

Comment: Do these drivers exists already? And when you say ship, you mean I can download them from somewhere right?

Comment: In the same archive file that contains the OpenOCD binary or source code.